# how should I wrtie the method for the requirement? -Abstract class

Tags: inheritance, interface, abstract, extend

Note: I done A,B,C already. So I have ask for part D.

```
  I have no idea how to write it? Is anyone can help me?
```

Consider the following classes:

```
public abstract class Vehicle {

    public boolean startEngine() {/* code */ }

    public abstract int getMaxSpeed();

    public abstract double getVehicleValue();

    }

public interface Rentable {

    public double getWeeklyRate();

    }

public interface UsesPremiumGas {

    public void fillTankWithPremiumGas(double gallons);

    }

public class Car extends Vehicle implements Rentable {/*code*/}

public class FancyCar extends Car implements UsesPremiumGas { /* code */ }

public class Bus extends Vehicle { /* code */ }
```

Answer the following questions (must means so that the code compiles).

a) Which methods must be implemented in the Car class?

b) Which methods must be implemented in the FancyCar class?

c) Which methods must be implemented in the Bus class?

d) The above classes are used to model a fleet of vehicles owned by a company.

Complete the method below that prints the cheapest weekly rate for the vehicles of the fleet that can be rented? In no vehicle can be rented, the method should state so.

```
/**
* Prints the cheapest weekly rate available among a fleet
* of vehicles, or prints that no vehicle can be rented.
* @param fleet the list of vehicles
*/
public void printCheapestWeeklyRate(ArrayList<Vehicle>fleet) {}
```

Comment: Thanks Joe for editing it for me!!

Answer (score 0):

For each Vehicle in the ArrayList, check whether it's an instance of the Rentable interface.

```
if(vehicle instanceof Rentable){...}
```

Call the method `getWeeklyRate()` for all the vehicles which are instanceof Rentable, and store the weekly rates in a Map with Vehicle object as key.

If the map is empty, then 'no vehicle can be rented'.

Else find the minimum value from the map and the corresponding vehicle is the cheapest to rent.

You can try the following code:

```
public void printCheapestWeeklyRate(ArrayList<Vehicle> fleet) 
    {
        Map<Vehicle,Double> rateMap = new HashMap<Vehicle,Double>();
        for(Vehicle vehicle : fleet)
        {
            if(vehicle instanceof Rentable)
            {
                rateMap.put(vehicle, vehicle.getWeeklyRate());
            }
        }
        if(rateMap.isEmpty()) // No vehicle is rentable
        {
            System.out.println("No vehicle is available for rent");
        }
        else // Some vehicles are rentable
        {
            Vehicle cheapestVehicle;
            Double min = Double.valueOf(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
            for(Map.Entry<Vehicle, Double> m : rateMap.entrySet()) // Get the cheapest vehicle
            {
                if(min.compareTo(m.getValue()) > 0)
                {
                    cheapestVehicle = m.getKey();
                }
            }
            // Print what you want as output using **cheapestVehicle**
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have no idea this method will under which class... is that important?

Comment: It depends on the way you want this method to be used.

Comment: thank you...i am reading that and try to make sense for myself...^_^

Comment: but when you writing that.... What class will you assume to put this method into? because I under your idea but some syntax is out of my knowledge now.(I am a beginner...hah)

Comment: I know for each loop...but I dont know map...and a lot of syxtax I haven't seen it during my class....

Comment: You can put this method into one of your utility classes as per your requirement. You can also put this method in the same class as that having the main() method and then call it from inside the main().

Comment: You can refer to these links for understanding Maps: [Map Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) and [HashMap Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)